# Why I can't get the permission "publish_actions" from Facebook on Android APP

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, publish

I am creating an application that needs posting on the timeline of User, and to make the test development I always used an App ID I had already created for some time and it works normal. However, I had to create a final version of the application so that does not work and created the same way I created the test App ID. Afterwards, I came across what appears to be a new privacy policy of Facebook "Submit Items for Approval" is my doubt.

Is really necessary from now when creating a new application has to submit revision of Facebook to be able to have permission "publish_actions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your app to be accessible to the public, aka publish on a random user's timeline, you now need to request for publish_actions permission. You can read all about permissions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0